# How can I keep successful and unsuccessful requests in separate arrays using forkJoin?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, fork-join

I want to keep successful and unsuccessful ids which using in requests in separate arrays using forkJoin. For example:

```
let ids = [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005];
let reqs = [];
let successReqs = [];
let failReqs = [];

ids.forEach(id => { 
    reqs.push(this.componentService.getVal(id)) 
});

forkJoin(reqs).subscribe(
    (results) => {
        console.log('ALL RESULT :', results);
    }, 
    (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

I have an "ids" array that holds ids to use in requests. Using these ids I am creating an array named "reqs" to use in forkJoin. But sometimes the service may fail, so for later use I want to keep the ids of the successful requests in the "successReqs" array and the ids of the failed requests in the "failReqs" array. But I couldn't find how to add these ids to arrays when it succeeds or fails. Returns the result of all requests in subscribe. How can I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it is optimal, but I would just catch error for each request, so as a result I have array of observables that never fail.

```
const reqs: Observable<any>[];

const neverFailReqs = reqs.map(req => req.pipe(map(result => ({success: true, result})))
                           .pipe(catchError(result => ({success: false, result}))));
forkJoin(neverFailReqs).subscribe(results => {
  console.log('Success: ' + results.filter(r => r.success).map(r => r.result));
  console.log('Fail: ' + results.filter(r => !r.success).map(r => r.result));
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can mark success and failure on each call and then separate them out later.
With this solution, you can see I map successful values to `success: true` and map errors to a stream that emits the error with `success: false`.

Later, once they've all run, I can filter the results based on the success flag I've created and then map the results back onto just the pure payload returned by each result.

I also keep the id of each call, regardless of success or failure.

```
const ids = [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005];

forkJoin(
  ids.map(id => 
    this.componentService.getVal(id).pipe(
      map(val => ({
        id,
        success: true,
        payload: val
      })),
      catchError(err => of({
        id,
        success: false,
        payload: err
      }))
    )
  )
).pipe(
  map(res => ({
    successReqs: res.filter(ob => ob.success).map(ob => ({
      id: ob.id,
      result: ob.payload
    })),
    failReqs: res.filter(ob => !ob.success).map(ob => ({
      id: ob.id,
      error: ob.payload
    }))
  }))
).subscribe(({successReqs, failReqs}) => {
    console.log('Success RESULT :', successReqs);
    console.log('Fail RESULT :', failReqs);
  }
);
```